# Dates not showing properly from 2 dates in php

Tags: php, datetime

Below code doesn't show the output of the month of 05 as input but if the date range is big then it shows the correct info.

```
//Code for finding All the Dates between TWO Date
//Code for finding month between two Date
$startDate = new DateTime("2018-04-26");
$inputEndDate = new DateTime("2018-05-03");
$inputEndDate->modify('+1day');//for increasing the day by 1

//for counting the month
$monthInterval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$monthPeriod   = new DatePeriod($startDate, $monthInterval, $inputEndDate);
$monthCount = 0;

foreach ($monthPeriod as $date) {
$endDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d')))); 

//last day of the month

$endDate->modify('+1 day');//for increasing the day by 1
if ($inputEndDate < $endDate) {
    $endDate = $inputEndDate;
}


//var_dump($endDate);

$dateRange = new DatePeriod($startDate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $endDate);
$startDate = $endDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->modify('-1 day');


echo "{$date->format('F')}-{$date->format('Y')}";
foreach($dateRange as $dateHeader){
    echo $dateHeader->format("Y-m-d");
}
$monthCount++;}
```

Output:

```
April-2018
2018-04-26
2018-04-27
2018-04-28
2018-04-29
2018-04-30
```

The output does not show the result of another month as in input.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: Is this translation correct?: You want to loop through all dates from a given start to a given end, increasing by day. right?

Comment: see Example #1 in the docs for [DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php). This should give you a hint!

Comment: sorry for my bad English jeff. the thing I want is to find the months from 2 dates first so it will loop only twice and along with month I want the dates for those 2 months

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_dates_through_range($start, $end, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $range = array();
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

    $range_end = new DateTime($end);
    $range_end->add($interval);

    $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($start), $interval, $range_end);

    foreach($period as $date) {
        $range[] = $date->format($format);
    }

    return $range;
 }
```

`get_dates_through_range('2018-04-30','2018-05-03')`

Outputs

```
array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2018-04-30"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2018-05-01"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2018-05-02"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "2018-05-03"
 }
```

Comment: this is not the answer i am looking for